# how to get HTML text before rendering to browser - using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf, itext

Want to save three to four months of development time. Because JSPs are already written.

Following program converts HTML into PDF format. Line 5 is written into the PDF file without HTML tags.
Now the question is, how can I get HTML text inside **Servlet** before JSP file renders it to the browser, so that I can pass that string/text to Line 11 in below program to convert entire HTML into PDF file.

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class App {  // Line 1
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
            IOException {
        try {
            String htmlText = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>"; // Line 5
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("Sample.pdf"));
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlText));  // Line 11
            document.close();
            // file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest a different approach? http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Servlet Filter and HttpServletResponseWrapper you can get JSP/Servlet output as String in Servlet filter.

This link will help: http://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/dump-request-and-response-using-javaxservletfilter/

Comment: at Loc Thanks for your answer. But answer doesn't help to retrieve HTML/Images/CSS which is being sent. I want to read HTML text inside the response object in filter class.  
We cannot read response object but we can append something into response. How to read HTML text inside response object inside filter ?

Comment: It helps you to get generated HTML code but it does not help you to get Image/CSS contents. After you have HTML code, You can parse HTML code using JSOUP.